# concatenate string in sql

Tags: sql

I have a database table "`create table t (s varchar, i int)`" with 100 records.

When I want to sum all 'i' fields, I invoke something like "`select sum(i) from  t`". Is there a way to concatenate the 's' fields? (`select concatenate(s) from t`)

In any sql dialect?

Comment: as a oneliner? Or are 'procedural' solutions also permitted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 - Concatenate String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579517/sql-server-2008-concatenate-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In any sql dialect?

There isn't an ANSI SQL specified way to do this across all SQL dialects.  If you want specific solutions for a particular DBMS, then sure, some have a ready made solution, and others have generalized solutions that are more complicated.

e.g.

- Oracle = WM_CONCAT
- MySQL = GROUP_CONCAT
- SQL Server = UDF / FOR XML PATH('') / recursive CTE

You need a question for each RDBMS you need the solution for, but you will find duplicate questions for each case already on StackOverflow.