# combine row with the same id in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's my query

```
select * 
from Owner_TABLE
```

Results:

```
RollNumber         People_ID   Owner
-------------------------------------------
444201000100100      12        Jame Bond
444201000100100      14        Sam Doris
444201000100200      16        Jane Doe
444201000100200      17        John Morris
444201000100300      18        Mandy Noor
```

My objective here is to work out how I can combine the Owner into one row with the same `RollNumber`?

Like =>

```
RollNumber         Owner
----------------------------------------
444201000100100    James Bond, Sam Doris
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server aggregate string concatenation"

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 - Concatenate String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579517/sql-server-2008-concatenate-string)

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887628/convert-multiple-rows-into-one-with-comma-as-separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi just want to share done the script and thanks for the people who posted their suggestions.

```
select p1.RollNumber,
(SELECT  FullName+', '  
FROM [dbo].[view_Owners_roll] p2 
WHERE
p1.RollNumber=p2.RollNumber 
for XML path(''),type).value('.','varchar(max)') 
as Name  from [dbo].[view_Owners_roll] p1 group by RollNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

To give an example of what the comments have been pointing to:

```
WITH ex as
(SELECT '444201000100100' as 'RollNumber', '12' as 'PeopleID', 'Jame Bond' as 'Owner'
UNION
SELECT '444201000100100', '14', 'Sam Doris'
UNION
SELECT '444201000100200', '16', 'Jane Doe'
UNION
SELECT '444201000100200', '17', 'John Morris'
UNION
SELECT '444201000100100', '18', 'Mandy Noor'
) 
SELECT RollNumber, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + e.Owner
                          FROM ex e
                          WHERE e.RollNumber = a.RollNumber
                          FOR XML PATH('')
                          ),1,2,'') as 'Owners'
FROM ex a
GROUP BY RollNumber
```

The `STUFF()` removes the remaining extra comma. The [`FOR XML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) clause formats the result set...for XML.

Try this to get a better feel of `FOR XML PATH`:

```
SELECT Owner
FROM ex
FOR XML PATH('')
```